# PHP syntax surprise with conditional operator "?:" and "OR"

Tags: php, syntax, operators, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Today, I was open-mouthed by the following:

```
$asdf = ((1 OR true) ? "asdf" : "fdsa");
var_dump($asdf); // print "asdf"

$asdf = (1 OR true) ? "asdf" : "fdsa";
var_dump($asdf); // print "asdf"

$asdf = (1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa");
var_dump($asdf); // print true

$asdf = 1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa";
var_dump($asdf); // print 1
```

Ok, the last does not surprise me much, but the third?
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is all about operator precedence and their associativity

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

`or` has lower precendence than `=` that is why it will be executed first

so `$asdf = 1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa";`

will be someting like

`($asdf = 1) or true ? :"asdf" : "fdsa"` that is why it will print 1.

`$a or $b` check whether $a or $b is true if $a is true then it is returned and it does not even go to check $b

In third case

`$asdf = (1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa");`

`()` has higher precedence than `=` so it will be executed before assignment.

To prove it

change OR to `||` which has higher precendence than `=`

```
$asdf = 1 || true ? "asdf" : "fdsa";

var_dump($asdf); // print asdf
```

Comment: But how the hell does `(1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa")` evaluate to `true`, not `"asdf"`?

Comment: because (1 OR "asdf") is true :P

Comment: Ah, it casts the result to boolean. [PHP, not something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_languages).

Comment: Yes it is logical expression.

Comment: Good answer, but aren't you assuming that the reader knows that `?` has higher precedence than `OR`? It feels like you missed that part of the explanation, where `$asdf = (1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa");` is simplified to `$asdf = (1 OR (true ? "asdf" : "fdsa"));`, thus `$asdf = 1 OR "asdf"` (which indeed is casted, as mentioned above). It's minor, and even a bit reduntant, but it may help people who are completely new to this. (EDIT: I'm a bit rusty with this, so if I've misunderstood something, excuse me. EDIT #2: I just saw that vural's answer explains this.)

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
// use () - result in brackets assigned to $asdf
$asdf = (1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa");
var_dump($asdf); // print true
```

And here:

```
// = has higher precedence so $asfd equals 1 
// and it doesn't matter what is the result of ternary operator
$asdf = 1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa";
// line equals to 
($asdf = 1) OR (true ? "asdf" : "fdsa");
// so $asdf is always 1 here
var_dump($asdf); // print 1
```

Answer (score 2):

$asdf = (1 OR true ? "asdf" : "fdsa");

It equals `(1 OR (true ? "asdf" : "fdsa"));`

And it equals `(1 OR "asdf");`

And this equals `true`;

1 OR "asdf" is not equal (1 OR "asdf"). If you don't use brackets, the statement after OR operator is not important anymore. You assigned the first element as value. But if you use brackets, the first element will be statement in brackets

Comment: Hi, (1 OR "asdf") will return bool(true).

Comment: This does not explain difference between third and fourth example.

Comment: Hi Volvox, 1 OR  "asdf" is not equal (1 OR "asdf"). If you use brackets, PHP return boolean as you will see in "Logical operators" page in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php.

Comment: But why it will return `int` when not using brackets?

Comment: @u_mulder; The statement after OR operator is not important anymore. You assigned the first element as value.

But if you use brackets, the first element will be statement in brackets.

Comment: But why didn't you explain it in your answer?

Comment: That was my fault, I changed my answer as more detailed.

Thanks your interest.